# Wht is the best solution for HTML to PDF (on Azure Web app)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation, azure-web-app-service, wkhtmltopdf

Actually  I am trying to convert html content to pdf using NReco PDF converter, however, this line of code pdfDoc.GeneratePdf(HtmlContent);
unable to get through on Azure web app, but it works normally on my dev environment. So my Question is which cloud service should i go for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Azure Apps (former WebSites) operate in restricted (partial-trust) environment and wkhtmltopdf.exe (that is internally used by NReco PdfGenerator wrapper) cannot be executed in this case directly from asp.net application.

update:

Unfortunately it will not work with Azure WebJobs as well: tasks are executed under the same (limited) environment as WebSites and GDI functions used by wkhtmltopdf are disabled.

If your ASP.NET app uses wkhtmltopdf-based component for PDF generation (doesn't matter how it is invoked - in separate process or as native DLL API) it will work only under Azure WebRole / WorkerRole / VM.

-- update 2017 --

Wkhtmltopdf (and NReco PdfGenerator wrapper) can be used with Azure Apps with VM-based subscription plan (Basic or higher). At least one issue still exists: it seems fonts API is still restricted and custom fonts cannot be rendered to PDF.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not familiar with Azure WebJobs, can you give me a place to start in order to archive this?

Comment: A WebJob won't help as it runs under the same sandbox. See [this document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) for sandbox details. At the end there is a list of unsupported frameworks.

Comment: @David Ebbo I see. Then my only is to switch from web app service to cloud service web role?

Comment: Unfortunately, this may be your only option right now if you must use this component :(

Comment: @David Ebbo You're absolutely right I forgot that wkhtmltopdf will not work under WebJobs because of GDI functions usage (I've updated my answer).

Comment: @DavidEbbo Thanks for your advice. I did switched to cloud service and it is working now.

Answer (score 7):

I've successfully managed to get wkhtmltopdf working on Azure functions backed by app service. I've used the OpenHtmltoPdf c# package which installs the wkhtmltopdf library automatically. I've published all the required files here:

https://gist.github.com/tmakin/80e1905094245c857c493b7879657095

**Update July 2018**
I've now switched to DinkToPdf for pdf on azure functions v2 which runs on net core. See here for more info:
https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2018/02/14/pdf-generation-in-azure-functions-v2.aspx

Comment: I used DinkToPdf on Azure Functions V2 as well, but it stopped working. Is it still working for you?

Comment: Can this be used now too ? I have a requirement for converting HTML file to PDF in Azure Function.

Comment: I've now switched to AWS lambda for hosing DinkToPdf based pdf conversions. Way quicker and much more flexible.