# Export html to pdf in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, pdf-generation

I want to export a piece of html to a pdf file but i do not any compatible nuget package.

When I try to install anyone: "X not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0)."

Does anyone know any way to export to a pdf using asp.net core??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export to pdf using ASP.NET 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983300/export-to-pdf-using-asp-net-5)

Comment: net core is different to asp.net 5, another framework, another libraries

Comment: AspNet Core 1.0 is the new name. AspNet 5 (formely AspNet vNext) was the original name but since it was a whole new product, MS decided to fully change it's name to AspNet Core.

Comment: Take a look at that answer. It's currently working in a PoC environment on IIS with core stack only and a subset of node as explained on the answer itself. Framework is set to exactly what you are using ;)

Comment: So not listed here previously - but the solution that worked great for me is the NuGet package of https://github.com/aaxelm/Rotativa.NetCore

Comment: This company offers a free comunity license and this forum post let's guess it will be available later this month: https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/127732/html-to-pdf-converter-asp-net-core

Answer (score 42):

You can use [jsreport .net sdk](https://jsreport.net/learn/dotnet) if you are in .net core 2.0 also without more complex node services. This includes among other features filters to convert your existing razor views into pdf. From the [docs](https://jsreport.net/learn/dotnet-aspnetcore):

1.
Install nugets [jsreport.Binary](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jsreport.Binary/), [jsreport.Local](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jsreport.Local/) and [jsreport.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jsreport.AspNetCore/)

2.
In you `Startup.cs` configure it as the following

```csharp
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();              
    services.AddJsReport(new LocalReporting()
        .UseBinary(JsReportBinary.GetBinary())
        .AsUtility()
        .Create());
}
```

3.
Then you need to add `MiddlewareFilter` attribute to the particular action and specify which conversion you want to use. In this case html to pdf conversion.

```csharp
[MiddlewareFilter(typeof(JsReportPipeline))]
public IActionResult Invoice()
{
    HttpContext.JsReportFeature().Recipe(Recipe.ChromePdf);
    return View();
}
```

You can reach bunch of other options for headers, footers or page layout on `JsReportFeature()`. Note that the same way you can also produce excel files from html. See more information in the [documentation](https://jsreport.net/learn/dotnet-aspnetcore).

PS: I'm the author of jsreport.

Comment: how to save the file after that?

Comment: how are the css and images files in razor handled? ajax calls? is the pdf output the same as what can be seen in browser?

Comment: Wow - I have never come across this before. I had a look at the site and it is a very comprehensive application you got going there. Very  impressed in how easily it integrates with ASP.NET - Before I used all sorts and had many nightmares. I owe you allot of beer for saving me time and making PDF generation easier.

Comment: how to include css? or is there also an option to only select a specific part of html to render to pdf?

Comment: had a lot of trouble with dependencies and nuget, it was horrible but I managed to configure it. Also, stackoveflow police keeps removing these comments. Maybe they are in love with the author of this

Comment: @Jan Blaha thanks, it works with 3.1 too.

Comment: Please do checkout my detailed article based on jsreport. https://code.soundaranbu.com/convert-html-to-pdf-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 24):

Copied from my original answer here [Export to pdf using ASP.NET 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41740342/5747654):

One way to generate pdf from html in .NET Core (without any .NET framework dependencies) is using Node.js from within the .NET Core application.
The following example shows how to implement an HTML to PDF converter in a clean ASP.NET Core Web Application project (Web API template).

Install the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices`

In Startup.cs add the line `services.AddNodeServices()` like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... all your existing configuration is here ...

    // Enable Node Services
    services.AddNodeServices();
}
```

Now install the required Node.js packages:

From the command line change working directory to the root of the .NET Core project and run these commands.

```
npm init
```

and follow the instructions to create the package.json file

```
npm install jsreport-core --save
npm install jsreport-jsrender --save
npm install jsreport-phantom-pdf --save
```

Create a file `pdf.js` in the root of the project containing

```js
module.exports = function (callback) {
    var jsreport = require('jsreport-core')();

    jsreport.init().then(function () {
        return jsreport.render({
            template: {
                content: '<h1>Hello {{:foo}}</h1>',
                engine: 'jsrender',
                recipe: 'phantom-pdf'
            },
            data: {
                foo: "world"
            }
        }).then(function (resp) {
            callback(/* error */ null, resp.content.toJSON().data);
        });
    }).catch(function (e) {
        callback(/* error */ e, null);
    })
};
```

Have a look [here](https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-core) for more explanation on `jsreport-core`.

Now create an action in an Mvc controller that calls this Node.js script

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction([FromServices] INodeServices nodeServices)
{
    var result = await nodeServices.InvokeAsync<byte[]>("./pdf");

    HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    string filename = @"report.pdf";
    HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("x-filename", filename);
    HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-filename");
    HttpContext.Response.Body.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
    return new ContentResult();
}
```

Off course you can do whatever you want with the `byte[]` returned from nodeServices, in this example I'm just outputting it from a controller action so it can be viewed in the browser.

You could also exchange the data between Node.js and .NET Core by a base64 encoded string using `resp.content.toString('base64')` in `pdf.js` and use
`var result = await nodeServices.InvokeAsync<byte[]>("./pdf");` in the action and then decode the base64 encoded string.

---

**Alternatives**

Most pdf generator solutions still depend on .NET 4.5/4.6 framework. But there seems to be some paid alternatives available if you don't like to use Node.js:

- [NReco.PdfGenerator.LT](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NReco.PdfGenerator.LT/)
- EVO HTML to PDF Converter Client for .NET Core
- Winnovative HTML to PDF Converter Client for .NET Core

I haven't tried any of these though.

I hope we will soon see some open source progress in this area.

Comment: Any idea how to use an existing Razor view (or any other html page) as input?

Comment: If you're just looking for a wkHtmlToPdf-Wrapper, you can use mine: https://github.com/ststeiger/wkHtmlToPdfSharp you'll have to modify it a bit for .NET Core.

Comment: @jao You should be able to change pdf.js with `module.exports = function (callback, html) {` and in the template set `content: html`, then in your action do `var result = await nodeServices.InvokeAsync<byte[]>("./pdf", razorRenderedHtmlString);`. However you will probably struggle with css unless you inline it in advance.

Comment: @sjolund thank you. I'm trying to customize options like so: `var jsreport = require('jsreport-core')({
        phantom: {
            margin: {
                top: "3cm",
                right: "0px",
                bottom: "3cm",
                left: "0px"
            },
            format: "A3",
        }
    });` but that doesn't work. Any idea why? How do you configure your phantom options?

Comment: found it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42472649/phantom-pdf-on-azure-in-asp-net-core?rq=1):  I need to add the phantom options in the template object.

Comment: TIL about using nodeservices in ASP.NET

Comment: This implementation caused me an error "System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are read-only, response has already started."

Comment: @Angel Romero This answer helped me get around that problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37395430/1551685

Answer (score 8):

You can check [DinkToPdf](https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf) library. It is a wrapper around wkhtmltopdf library for .NET Core.

Synchronized converter

Use this converter in multi threaded applications and web servers. Conversion tasks are saved to blocking collection and executed on a single thread.

```
var converter = new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools());
```

Define document to convert

```
var doc = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
{
    GlobalSettings = {
        ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
        Orientation = Orientation.Landscape,
        PaperSize = PaperKind.A4Plus,
    },
    Objects = {
        new ObjectSettings() {
            PagesCount = true,
            HtmlContent = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In consectetur mauris eget ultrices  iaculis. Ut                               odio viverra, molestie lectus nec, venenatis turpis.",
            WebSettings = { DefaultEncoding = "utf-8" },
            HeaderSettings = { FontSize = 9, Right = "Page [page] of [toPage]", Line = true, Spacing = 2.812 }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: This works really well with Kestrel, but not on IIS. Any ideas why?

Comment: Problem with IIS is how IIS manage app pools. To resolve that issue Remoting tools should be used but they are not supported in .NET Core. If anyone have solution for this problem please comment.

Comment: Have a look at [https://github.com/TheSalarKhan/PhantomJs.NetCore] it works on IIS too, and unlike wkhtmltopdf it works on linux, Mac and windows.

Comment: wkhtmltopdf works on Linux, Mac and Windows you just need to get right version of the library.

Comment: it generated pdf the first time and then refused to generate the second time i don't know why

Comment: Can you provide sample or tell more about how you use it? Do you use it web server? Do you use basic or synchronized converter?

Comment: @maztt did you solve that problem? We are experiencing the same issue in a netcore 1.1 app. It seems to be a threading issue but I can't find anything wrong in their SynchronizerConverter

Comment: @Steve no we didn't solved the problem . go for 2.1 now as it released, managing third party libraries in 1.1 is a living hell. What we did is to create a project in dotnetframework web api using compaitable itextsharp and then called it

Comment: @Steve, SynchronizedConverter must be declared as singleton.

Comment: @user1646245 yes after a bit of debugging on the code we were able to discover the problem exactly in this singleton issue. To be honest we have it as singleton but someone decided to reinitilize it everytime the export to pdf routine was called. Now it works correctly

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue! I wanted to generate PDF files from HTML strings. I then came across [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org) which is a command line utility for converting html files to pdf. I wrote a cross-platform wrapper over it in C# for .NET CORE and its working great on Linux! Though as of now its only for 64-bit Linux, because that is the only platform .NET Core Supports currently.
The project can be found [here](https://github.com/TheSalarKhan/PhantomJs.NetCore)

```
PhantomJs.NetCore.PdfGenerator gen = new PhantomJs.NetCore.PdfGenerator("/path/to/pantomjsfolder");
string outputFilePath = gen.GeneratePdf("<h1>Hello</h1>","/folder/to/write/file/in");
```

Comment: What of mac developers Lenny ?

Comment: I felt bad when I saw you archived your repo.

Answer (score 3):

Below points may help.

- **Do it in Server Side**
- If the html is in the server then give a try using below packages also.
- Package [Puppeteer Sharp](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp) , Check [Tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/pdf-generation-with-puppeteer-sharp/)
- Package [Playwright Dotnet](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-dotnet), Check [Tutorial](https://www.meziantou.net/generate-pdf-files-using-an-html-template-and-playwright.htm)
- **Do it in Client Side** (This will also help if cross platform scenario doesn't work.)
- [JsPdf](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF) , Check [Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript)
- [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer), Check [Tutorial](https://medium.com/@fmoessle/use-html-and-puppeteer-to-create-pdfs-in-node-js-566dbaf9d9ca)
- Last option just print PDF using browser, Check [Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239513/print-pdf-directly-from-javascript)
- **Other Points**
- Just don't choose some random packages from internet because it may have security issues, privacy etc, instead check if big companies like Microsoft , Google etc have some free  open source packages, Once the packages are selected verify it with security team if required or check the reviews and downloads. Also check their licensing page if its free or paid.
- Give a try to [gotenberg](https://github.com/gotenberg/gotenberg),
  [c#
  example](https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/GotenbergSharpApiClient) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/10nefyb/html_to_pdf_free_library_net_60/) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/meejg4/best_free_net_core_50_html_to_pdf_to_use/).
- If `Linux` containers have issue, Create a API outside container to convert `HTML` to `PDF` and try calling your new API inside your container app or try gotenberg they have container and sdk versions.
- Also based on the requirements and performance trade offs, decide do this in server side or client side.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution working for ASP.NET Core 2.0, which allows either to **generate dynamic PDF files** from `cshtml`, directly send them to users and/or save them before sending.

To complement [Jan Blaha answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45840308/4881677), for more flexibility, you may want to use the following code:

```cs
/// Generate a PDF from a html string
async Task<(string ContentType, MemoryStream GeneratedFileStream)> GeneratePDFAsync(string htmlContent)
{
    IJsReportFeature feature = new JsReportFeature(HttpContext);
    feature.Recipe(Recipe.PhantomPdf);
    if (!feature.Enabled) return (null, null);
    feature.RenderRequest.Template.Content = htmlContent;
    var report = await _RenderService.RenderAsync(feature.RenderRequest);
    var contentType = report.Meta.ContentType;
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    report.Content.CopyTo(ms);
    return (contentType, ms);
}
```

Using a class to render cshtml files as string, you may use the [following service](https://gist.github.com/JeanCollas/22154325c6da339d5ac0060f91ea7d53) (which can be injected as a scoped service):

```cs
public class ViewToStringRendererService: ViewExecutor
{
    private ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public ViewToStringRendererService(
        IOptions<MvcViewOptions> viewOptions,
        IHttpResponseStreamWriterFactory writerFactory,
        ICompositeViewEngine viewEngine,
        ITempDataDictionaryFactory tempDataFactory,
        DiagnosticSource diagnosticSource,
        IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider,
        ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        : base(viewOptions, writerFactory, viewEngine, tempDataFactory, diagnosticSource, modelMetadataProvider)
    {
        _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task<string> RenderViewToStringAsync<TModel>(string viewName, TModel model)
    {
        var context = GetActionContext();

        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        var result = new ViewResult()
        {
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(
                    metadataProvider: new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(),
                    modelState: new ModelStateDictionary())
            {
                Model = model
            },
            TempData = new TempDataDictionary(
                    context.HttpContext,
                    _tempDataProvider),
            ViewName = viewName,
        };

        var viewEngineResult = FindView(context, result);
        viewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(originalLocations: null);

        var view = viewEngineResult.View;

        using (var output = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                context,
                view,
                new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(
                    metadataProvider: new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(),
                    modelState: new ModelStateDictionary())
                {
                    Model = model
                },
                new TempDataDictionary(
                    context.HttpContext,
                    _tempDataProvider),
                output,
                new HtmlHelperOptions());

            await view.RenderAsync(viewContext);

            return output.ToString();
        }
    }
    private ActionContext GetActionContext()
    {
        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
        httpContext.RequestServices = _serviceProvider;
        return new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to find the <see cref="IView"/> associated with <paramref name="viewResult"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actionContext">The <see cref="ActionContext"/> associated with the current request.</param>
    /// <param name="viewResult">The <see cref="ViewResult"/>.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="ViewEngineResult"/>.</returns>
    ViewEngineResult FindView(ActionContext actionContext, ViewResult viewResult)
    {
        if (actionContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(actionContext));
        }

        if (viewResult == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(viewResult));
        }

        var viewEngine = viewResult.ViewEngine ?? ViewEngine;

        var viewName = viewResult.ViewName ?? GetActionName(actionContext);

        var result = viewEngine.GetView(executingFilePath: null, viewPath: viewName, isMainPage: true);
        var originalResult = result;
        if (!result.Success)
        {
            result = viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewName, isMainPage: true);
        }

        if (!result.Success)
        {
            if (originalResult.SearchedLocations.Any())
            {
                if (result.SearchedLocations.Any())
                {
                    // Return a new ViewEngineResult listing all searched locations.
                    var locations = new List<string>(originalResult.SearchedLocations);
                    locations.AddRange(result.SearchedLocations);
                    result = ViewEngineResult.NotFound(viewName, locations);
                }
                else
                {
                    // GetView() searched locations but FindView() did not. Use first ViewEngineResult.
                    result = originalResult;
                }
            }
        }

        if(!result.Success)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Couldn't find view '{0}'", viewName));

        return result;
    }


    private const string ActionNameKey = "action";
    private static string GetActionName(ActionContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (!context.RouteData.Values.TryGetValue(ActionNameKey, out var routeValue))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var actionDescriptor = context.ActionDescriptor;
        string normalizedValue = null;
        if (actionDescriptor.RouteValues.TryGetValue(ActionNameKey, out var value) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            normalizedValue = value;
        }

        var stringRouteValue = routeValue?.ToString();
        if (string.Equals(normalizedValue, stringRouteValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return normalizedValue;
        }

        return stringRouteValue;
    }

}
```

Then to conclude, in your controller, supposing the razor cshtml view template to be `/Views/Home/PDFTemplate.cshtml` you may use the following.

Note: The `cshtml` file may need to be copied when published (even if views are compiled).

```cs
var htmlContent = await _ViewToStringRendererService.RenderViewToStringAsync("Home/PDFTemplate", viewModel);
(var contentType, var generatedFile) = await GeneratePDFAsync(htmlContent);
Response.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = $"attachment; filename=\"{System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(fileName)}\"";

// You may save your file here
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(folder, fileName), FileMode.Create))
{
   await generatedFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}
// You may need this for re-use of the stream
generatedFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

return File(generatedFile.ToArray(), "application/pdf", fileName);
```

Comment: how to declare the `_RenderService`?

Comment: `_RenderService` is the `ViewToStringRendererService` just below. 
It should be injected as scoped or Transient during startup.

Comment: @LiquidCore please elaborate. Besides the ViewToStringRendererService, which is useful in several cases, it is a 15 lines piece of code

Answer (score 1):

On the server-side, you can output pdf of a html and use library that generate PDF from HTML string .NET Core after you got pdf, you need to pass it to the library see this link to convert HTML to PDF in .NET.

install nuget package : [Select.HtmlToPdf.NetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Select.HtmlToPdf.NetCore/)

```
HtmlToPdf htmlToPdf = new HtmlToPdf();
            htmlToPdf.Options.PdfPageOrientation = PdfPageOrientation.Portrait;
            // put css in pdf
            htmlToPdf.Options.MarginLeft = 15;
            htmlToPdf.Options.MarginRight = 15;
            ---------------------------
            string url = "<html><head></head><body>Hello World</body></html>"
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = htmlToPdf.ConvertHtmlString(url);
            byte[] pdf = pdfDocument.Save();
            //convert to memory stream
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(pdf);
            pdfDocument.Close();
            //if want to transfer stream to file 
            File(stream, "application/pdf", Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf");
```

Comment: Beware: this answer is no good for files more than 5 pages long

Comment: This will work on windows platform only.

Comment: Any Mac platform solutions?