# Generate a Pdf Document from MemoryStream in .netCore 2.0

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-core-2.0

I want to generate a Pdfdocument using fileStream in .netcore 2.0.

Before, I was generating the Pdf using .net framework's library but I can't find any 3rd party libraries for .core

The code below is using .net framework Spire.Pdf where I  create the PdfDocument from the Stream.

```
        Stream fileStream =new MemoryStream(buffer);            
        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(fileStream);
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML to PDF in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net)

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/39364687/3451919

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers.
In the end I used PdfSharp to implement my solution. The code below is using this library.

```
        Stream fileStream =new MemoryStream(buffer);

        PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument doc;

        doc = PdfReader.Open(fileStream);
```