# How to publish ASP.NET Core with node.js modules for IIS

Tags: node.js, iis, asp.net-core

I was trying to find a way to build a pdf from a html code with .net core 2, I found a way to do it with some node.js libaries(that works local) but when publish the project and install  in IIS doesn't work

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "jsreport-core": "^1.5.1",
    "jsreport-jsrender": "^1.0.2",
    "jsreport-phantom-pdf": "^1.4.6"
  }
}
```

this is my csproj file

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <StartupObject />
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.5</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="obj\**" />
    <Content Remove="obj\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="obj\**" />
    <None Remove="obj\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\uploads\banner\" />   
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>

    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="6.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="7.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="JWT" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
    <Content Include="node_modules\foo\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
    <Content Include="node_modules\**" />
    <Content Include=".\pdf.js" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind />
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptOutFile />
    <TypeScriptOutDir />
    <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
    <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptMapRoot />
    <TypeScriptSourceRoot />
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

the error is "cannot find module 'jsreport-core'"

Comment: It seems that not every package got copied. Shouldn't you have `CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest"`in `<Content Include="node_modules"`?

Comment: just FYI [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45840308/1660996) you can find how to use jsreport-core without node service.