# DinkToPDF pdf result is different from the HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dinktopdf

I tried to convert html to pdf by using [DinkToPDF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DinkToPdf/).

Unfortunately the pdf result is different than source HTML.

Here are my DinkToPdf settings:

```
var globalSettings = new GlobalSettings
{
    ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
    Orientation = Orientation.Portrait,
    PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
    DocumentTitle = title,
    Out = string.Empty,
};

var objectSettings = new ObjectSettings
{
    PagesCount = true,
    HtmlContent = htmlBody,
    WebSettings = { DefaultEncoding = "utf-8" }
};
```

Sample Source HTML

[image: sample source html]

Sample PDF result

[image: dinktopdf result]

Is it a bug?
Or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: A PDF is not a browser. It will render differently. You just have to make a simplified html page for pdf or create a PDF without html.

Answer (score 1):

DinkToPdf is based on wkhtmltopdf and doesn't support a lot of modern CSS.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55432418/net-core-dinktopdf-not-showing-bootstrap-columns-properly) StackOverflow post on DinkToPdf.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a Bug. As explained by @zvons, it wont support Modern CSS like Flexbox.
Further there are many Global settings which alter font depth, spacing etc. between characters.

Eg: DPI is important setting for PDF. This cant be done from CSS.
Alter Global settings to achieve the result.