# JSReport: ASP.net Core Deployment - Could not load file or assembly jsreport.Local

Tags: asp.net-core, dll, web-deployment, filenotfoundexception, jsreport

I am using ASP.net Core 3.0 and I wanted to have `html to pdf` export functionality, I found JSReport as a solution So I followed the [Jon Blaha's Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45840308/4567504) of JSReport .net SDK to export html to pdf, I have successfully install nugets `jsReport.Binary`, `jsReport.Local` and `jsReport.AspNetCore` in my development machine.
Following are the dlls that got installed

- jsReport.AspNetCore.dll (v2.0.2.0)
- jsReport.Client.dll (v3.0.1.0)
- jsReport.Local.dll (v2.2.2.0)
- jsReport.Shared.dll (v2.1.0.0)
- jsReport.Types.dll (v2.6.1.0)
- jsReport.Binary.dll (v2.7.1.0)

I have followed the Jon Blaha's implementation and `Export html to pdf` working fine on my dev machine. But when I uploaded dlls with my project's published dll my application got stopped working

> an error occurred while starting the application

I searched for this error and I found that I had to enable logging through my `web.config` by using

```
stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
```

to get the actual error message behind my startup failure.

After doing the required changes to my `web.config` and I got the log file generated, it says

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'jsreport.Local, Version=2.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[6]
      Application startup exception
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'jsreport.Local, Version=2.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'jsreport.Local, Version=2.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at Technicianspk.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Invoke>g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Build>b__0(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<UseStartup>b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I doubled check my wwwroot directory through FTP using FileZilla and I had all these required jsReport dlls on my server but still I am getting file not found.

I even compared the dll versions and made sure my `.csproj` file reference all the required jsreport dlls but still its unable to find `jsReport.Local.dll`.

I have `jsReport.Local.dll` in my dev machine and also in my server's wwwroot directory where all the other dlls are present including my `project.dll` and `project.views.dll` and `project.exe` etc.

My `cs.proj` file also has the following

```
<ItemGroup>
 <PackageReference Include="jsreport.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.2" />
 <PackageReference Include="jsreport.Binary" Version="2.7.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="jsreport.Client" Version="3.0.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="jsreport.Local" Version="2.2.2" />
 <PackageReference Include="jsreport.Shared" Version="2.1.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="jsreport.Types" Version="2.6.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Suggested by Jan Blaha on [Github issue](https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-dotnet/issues/48#issuecomment-609382191).

> Please try to create just a hello world app. Does it work there?
>   Please upload somewhere your project and how the deployment output looks like.
>
> I tried preparing a new asp.net core mvc 3 app. Referenced jsreport.
>   Published to the folder and there is no issue when running the asp.net
>   server through outputted exe.

I created a new hello world app and referenced jsReport and published it and uploaded it to my subdomain for testing purpose. and I got couple of reasons for this to not work

> 1. There was a file permission issue on my server
> 2. jsReport tried to create a folder on the root directory called 'jsReport' that was not being created because of folder access rights (file permission issues)
> 3. I was not uploading 2 of json files `projectname.deps.json` and `projectname.runtimeconfig.json` during my uploading process

After doing the above changes to my main domain, the site finally got up working!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by use this code in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddJsReport(new LocalReporting()
                .KillRunningJsReportProcesses()
                .UseBinary(JsReportBinary.GetBinary())
                .AsUtility()
                .KeepAlive(false)
                .Create()
            );
```