# Cross platform nuget HTML to PDF in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, html-to-pdf

I'm working on the task to convert HTML to PDF. Our site is hosted on a Linux Docker container.

I tried many NuGet packages, from last week, but could not find a proper solution.

I tried all these packages:

- Itextsharp
- Select.Htmltopdf
- wkhtmltopdf
- hiqpdf

Can anyone suggest or show an example for a cross platform HTML to PDF conversion library?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "didn't work" is not a good problem description. There are some libraries available (but asking for libraries is not a good question for stackoverflow). There are commercial products available and you could invoice an external app (e.g. headless browser). Note that many of those libs depend on Ghostscript which may be a problem due to its AGLP license.

Comment: I asked ghostscript sales for a commercial license and they recommended: https://www.activepdf.com/. Nice overview in the web: https://www.paperplane.app/blog/modern-html-to-pdf-conversion-2019/

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I don't found any solution which was working on both platform. Windows as well as linux docker. If you any reference for same please share so I can implement in my task.

Comment: You mentioned some options and afaik they should work on linux (and so inside your docker container) too. I already gave you two more options. You'll need to evaluate those options and if you have problems implementing one of them, come back and post a new question with all problem details that help others to understand your problem.

Comment: @KiranJoshi Have you found any solution for this, I'm also facing the same issue

Comment: @SachithWickramaarachchi no not yet.

Comment: @KiranJoshi Is there some progress?

Comment: @DavidKrásný no buddy I have move to js for that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I used [HakanL/WkHtmlToPdf-DotNet](https://github.com/HakanL/WkHtmlToPdf-DotNet) which is a wrapper for the [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) tool. The package includes all necessary binaries for running on Windows, Linux, MacOSX and Docker. I tested it on Windows and Linux with .NET 6 and it worked without any problems.

Comment: Also try **multiple options** in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77058015/2218697) post.